# xslt - resolve schema in target xml

Tags: java, xslt

I transform one xml to other using xslt.
The point is that in target xml I need shema to be resolved.
Where link to this schema should reside? Please, provide me with right approach for that.
Is the used API enough:

```
import javax.xml.transform.*;

public class Main implements URIResolver{
private File root;
public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, TransformerConfigurationException, 
FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    tFactory.setURIResolver(new URIResolver() {
         public Source resolve(String href, String base) {
             if (href.endsWith("in.xml")) {
                 return new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("in.xml"));
             } else { 
                 return null; 
             } 
         } 
     }); 
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("rules.xsl"));
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource("in.xml"), new StreamResult(new          FileOutputStream("out.xml")));
    System.out.println("************* The result is in out.xml *************");

@Override
public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
     StreamSource source = new StreamSource(getInputStream(href));
          // this works with saxon7/saxon6.5.2/xalan
         source.setSystemId(href);
           return source;
}
  protected InputStream getInputStream(String path)
         {
        InputStream file = null;

           try
               {
              // load from a dir
              file = new FileInputStream(new File(this.root, path));
           }
           catch (FileNotFoundException e)
               {
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.println("File not found");
           }

       return file;
     }
```

in.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <enfinity
 xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.1/core/impex-dt">..
```

rules.xsl:

```
 <custom-attribute name="isPerformance" dt:dt="int">1</custom-attribute>
```

I got:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "dt" for attribute "dt:dt" associated with an element type "custom-attribute" is not bound.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

First step is to solve the SAXParseException. This is caused because your rules.xsl file is not namespace-well-formed. You can't use the namespace prefix dt in your stylesheet unless it is declared in the stylesheet. So add xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.1/core/impex-dt" to the stylesheet.

If the file you have shown as rules.xsl is the entire file, then it's going to fail because this file is not an XSLT stylesheet.

I can't really help you with your first question, about the reference to a schema. It would help to show what output you want to produce. But you seem to have some much more basic problems to solve first.